# log4j with multiple WebLogic instances

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, weblogic, cluster-computing

I'm creating a Java Web Services application. I intend to run multiple instances of WebLogic on each machine in a cluster.

I'd like each application instance to write to its own log file, but I'm not sure how to do so without creating instance specific log4j properties files. Is there some way for me to dynamically determine the WebLogic instance and append it to a log file name? Is there a better way to do this that I haven't seen?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Leon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`${weblogic.Name}` will give you the name of the Weblogic instance. You can use this as part of the filename within log4j like below.

```
log4j.appender.file.File=/<path>/myapplog_${weblogic.Name}.log
```

We also use this attribute within the log file as below

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.SSS} ${weblogic.Name} <myapp> [-] %-5p %m \: %c-(%L) %n
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I did a little research on your suggestion and it worked just as you described. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that you have to use `${sys:weblogic.Name}` if you are using log4j2.